# Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Error message:

> Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at 'C:\Users\KIRON\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe'.

I have reinstalled python and pycharm, but the same problem occurs. I have tried using both python 3.9 and 3.7.6.

Comment: Hi can you post the errors that you've been getting?

Comment: Can you also add to your question where pip.exe lives and what you path looks like.

Comment: What is the command you tried to run? Please include it too.